# URL rewriting match is always "index.php"

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to set up the RewriteEngine so it would redirect:

```
http://www.url.com/some/parameter
```

to

```
http://www.url.com/index.php?page=some&topic=parameter
```

or something similar.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))*/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
```

When I visit http://www.myurl.com/test/param now it does not add the parameters correctly (or does not work at all).
When I print all $_GET entries it always says:

```
param1 -> index.php
param2 -> 

//Code:
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v)
    print($k . ' -> ' . $v . '<br/>');
```

I hope anyone has an idea.

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that it works if I write it like: http://www.myurl.com/index.php/param1/param2, but I don't want index.php in that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond` to prevent this rule to execute 2nd time:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))*/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

In the absence of these 2 `RewriteCond` your rule is executing 2nd time also since pattern is still matching `/index.php` URI.

Comment: Thanks, it works. How would I redirect http://www.myurl.com/ to http://www.myurl.com/index.php?page=home ?

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest creating a new question for that since that is very different from this current problem and suggesting code in comments isn't easy due to formatting issues.

Comment: I will google and see if I find something that works for me, if that does not help I will create a new question.

Comment: Yes sure, feel free to leave a comment here when you create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

With `[L]` you also need to specify `[QSA]`, which means 'query string append'.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))*/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html